# Can I make an iOS/Android app "ring", to force the user to respond to a push notification?

Tags: android, ios, swift, capacitor

I have a food ordering app and I need to inform the restaurants of a new order. I have a Capacitor app which often runs in the background of tablets/phones of the restaurant. As a result, they sometimes miss an order.

In order to solve this, it would be great if I could ring the device as if an alarm goes off or if the device gets a call. Then they can swipe away the notification to stop it or something like that, to make sure they saw it. I would choose the sound myself so that it isn't obnoxious.

Is anything like that possible?

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible but,
you should know the following:
for Android:

1. 1-create a foreground service to keep notification appears to the
   restaurants, in this case the restaurant can not hide the
   notification.
2. once the restaurant receive the notification just
   sent an event to the foreground service to handle the action and the
   data.
3. start the order activity from foreground service, once the
   activity is created just play a sound.

for IOS,
it should be the same but i don't know how to create a foreground service in IOS.